# How to split two json in one string parameter

Tags: json, string, salesforce, apex

I have a string like this 
{"abc":"123","cde":"234"}.{"iss":"cc.home.com","sub":"1323ddkdfd","nonce":"jdkaofjdfd"}
I want to split this string, but do not know what should I use to split it,
because I can't use '\.' or ',', since they all exist in the json value
Any idea what should I do with this,any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = "{\"abc\":\"123\",\"cde\":\"234\"}.{\"iss\":\"cc.home.com\",\"sub\":\"1323ddkdfd\",\"nonce\":\"jdkaofjdfd\"}.{\"iss\":\"cc.home.com\",\"sub\":\"1323ddkdfd\",\"nonce\":\"jdkaofjdfd\"}";
        String[] sArr = s.split("\\}\\.\\{");
        for (int i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
            System.out.println(sArr[i]+"}");
            else if(i == sArr.length-1)
                System.out.println("{"+sArr[i]);
            else
                System.out.println("{"+sArr[i]+"}");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
{"abc":"123","cde":"234"}
{"iss":"cc.home.com","sub":"1323ddkdfd","nonce":"jdkaofjdfd"}
{"iss":"cc.home.com","sub":"1323ddkdfd","nonce":"jdkaofjdfd"}
```